# Fastest way to fetch value of just one field of an instance in Django

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset

Let's say I have a model like this:

```
class A(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    (more fields)
```

I want to fetch value of just title field of an instance. I can either use `filter`:

```
A.objects.filter(id=1).values_list('title', flat=True)
```

which generates a SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT "app_table_a"."title" FROM "app_table_a" WHERE ("app_table_a"."a_id" = 1) LIMIT whatever
```

or use `get`:

```
A.objects.get(id=1).title
```

which generates this:

```
SELECT "app_table_a"."id", "app_table_a"."title", ... ,"app_table_a"."all the fields in the model" FROM "app_table_a" WHERE ("app_table_a"."a_id" = 1)
```

The difference is in `SELECT` part of queries, which gives the impression that the first approach is a better option. But when I look at execution time of those statements, I don't see a meaningful difference and both statements fluctuate around, for example, 25ms.

So, my question is whether there is any difference, performance-wise (specially with huge databases and models with many fields), or I am just twisting everything with long statements?

Comment: You might have a look at `only()`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#only

Comment: In my opinion, readability is more important than micro-optimisation. The second option is far more readable.

Comment: @Brandon thanks for the hint; that was handy!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i agree with you.There is no much significant difference in between them(in perfomance when only one record) because, behind the scenes the django `get()` method runs the `filter()` method, but checks that the filter results set is exactly one record.